# SSRS report builder sum all and exclude one

Tags: reporting-services

I HAVE TAX COLUMN AND AT THE BOTTOM I WANT TO HAVE THE SUM OF ALL ROWS.
IN MY CASE I WANT TO EXCLUDE ONE PRODUCT FROM IT
BELOW IS THE RESULT THAT IS NEED ('C' IS EXCLUDED)

```
  | ROW | TAX  |
  | ----| -----|
  | A   | 20   |
  | B   | 30   |
  | C   | 10   |
```

|SUM        | 50   |

Comment: STOP YELLING, YOU'RE HURTING MY EYES :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An IIF can be used inside the aggregate function to replace the value of TAX with zero if ROW is C.

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!ROW.Value = "C", 0, Fields!TAX.Value))
```

If the TAX field is not an INTEGER, then you may need to wrap the 0 in a CDEC function to convert it to decimal.

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!ROW.Value = "C", CDEC(0), Fields!TAX.Value))
```